# Issues when dwm was patched with tab and pango

Tags: linux, fonts, dwm, software-conflict

I have patched dwm 6.0 with [dwm-6.0-pertag-tab-v2a.diff](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/tab) and [dwm-6.0-pango.diff](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/pango). The topbar works correctly with true font type (Sans). But the tabbar is blank without title. How can I fix this? I have no experience with C programming.